# Android: keep background view change foreground view

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

I'm making an app that uses a video feed. There will be several UI elements displayed on the screen. Based on what buttons the user clicks, the UI will evolve and show different buttons/options.

What's the best way to implement the changing UI in terms of activities. 
Should I use 1 activity,(so that I only have to load the video buffer one time), and update the UI setup within that activity? OR, should I have a different activitty for each UI combination, reloading the video in the background each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will Fragments be a good option here?